# Mgt people picker is not working for group-ids attribute

Tags: graph, microsoft-teams

const groupids = '0ab449e7-5d06-4f8c-9bb0-de87e7f3f684,fae2d5ac-a9f6-42c2-9a4c-20143e49b21b';

Sorry, no people were found

mgt people picker is not fetching the users from the given group ids instead its fetching all the users. If i given hte attribue group-id and given the single group id its fetching the users from that group only but for multiple groups its not working

Comment: Please have look into this-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/people-picker

Comment: Now its working fine the issue is with the version we are using the mgt version of 2.3 its not working with 2.3 upgraded to 2.6 then its working fine Thanks